# How do I save the items in the list in my flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class FavoriteList extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_FavoriteListState createState() => _FavoriteListState();
}

class _FavoriteListState extends State<FavoriteList> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 53,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Card(
          child: Container(
            child: ListTile(
              contentPadding:
                  EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
              subtitle: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image.asset('lib/images/${images[index]}'),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    nameOfSite[index],
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              trailing: Icon(
                alreadySaved ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
                color: alreadySaved ? Colors.red : null,
              ),
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  if (alreadySaved) {
                    _saved.remove(context);
                  } else {
                    _saved.add(context);
                  }
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

I'm creating a favorite tab in which I want to store the items which I save by tapping on that favorite icon along the row.
I'm not able to add items in a different list when I click on the icon to save it. Any help please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is the list? If it's a list that is supposed to be shared between screens you might have to look in to `Provider`.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/theyashjha/aioapp) is my code. If you can check what's wrong in it, please!?

Answer (score 0):

make item class

```
class item{
  bool fav = false;
}


 // your code
 trailing: item[index].fav == false ? Icon(UnfavIcon) : Icon(favIcon)
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              item[index].fav = true / false ; 
            });
           },
```